# Команда cd в скрипте shell

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell

Записал я в скриптик `gotodir3.sh` следующую команду:

```
cd dir1/dir2/dir3
```

И положил его в корень рабочей папки юзера (т.е. в папку `home/username`), где располагается директория `dir1`. Поставил права доступа `rwxrwxrwx`. Запускаю скриптик `./gotodir3.sh` и остаюсь в корне рабочей папки юзера! Почему?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255414/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-bash-shell-script

Коротко содержание ссылки:
скрипт запускает свою версию оболочки (точнее будет сказать - экземпляр оболочки или subshell). В этом экземпляре он действительно меняет директорию, в чем легко убедиться добавив команду ls после cd ...
Но по завершению скрипта, Вы возвращаетесь в тот экземпляр shell'а, из которого вы его вызывали.

Comment: Добавление #!/bin/sh (#!/bin/bash или любого другого шелла) ничего не изменит.

Comment: Ага, я заметил.
Воспользовался решением запускать скрипт с точкой: `. gotodir3.sh`

Answer (score 2):

текущий каталог — это **свойство** процесса.

меняется оно (в *posix*-совместимых оболочках) при помощи встроенной в оболочку **команды** (не программы!) `cd`.

как и подавляющее большинство иных свойств процесса, это свойство (по умолчанию) наследуется дочерними процессами от родительского. «обратного» же (от дочернего — родительскому) способа наследования, к счастью, нет.

давая операционной системе команду выполнить какой-нибудь файл (вводя путь к нему, или указывая лишь имя, если он находится в одном из каталогов, перечисленных в переменной окружения `PATH`), вы тем самым порождаете **новый** процесс. среди прочих он получает от родительского процесса и значение свойства «текущий каталог», которое затем самостоятельно может менять сколько угодно раз. но по завершении этого процесса все его свойства «умирают» вместе с ним, не оказывая влияния на родительский процесс.

потому запуск какого бы то ни было процесса для смены текущего каталога — не имеет смысла.

---

но в случае оболочек есть нюанс: понятный оболочке скрипт можно **интерпретировать** средствами самой оболочки, в контексте текущего процесса. и если в скрипте встретится команда `cd ...`, то она, естественно, повлияет на текущий процесс оболочки, и пользователь по завершении процесса интерпретации обнаружит, что «его» текущий каталог — изменился.

для интерпретации в *posix*-совместимых оболочках служит встроенная команда `source` и её синоним `.` (точка):

```
$ source /путь/к/скрипту
$ .      /путь/к/скрипту
```

---

есть ещё (как минимум) два способа изменить свойство «текущий каталог»:

1. с помощью заготовленного заранее *псевдонима* (удобно помещать их в конфигурационный файл оболочки — `.bashrc`, `.zshrc` и т.д. и т.п.). например, добавив такой *псевдоним* (*alias*):

   ```
   $ alias cd1="cd /каталог"
   ```

   можно будет командой `cd1` изменять текущий каталог процесса оболочки на `/каталог`.
2. с помощью заготовленной заранее функции (их можно сохранять в том же файле). например, такая функция:

   ```
   $ cd2() { cd /ещё/каталог; }
   ```

   позволит с помощью команды `cd2` изменять текущий каталог на `/ещё/каталог`.

---

за рамками ответа остаётся ещё, например, связка `dirs`/`pushd`/`popd`. хотя эти команды и не *posix*-совместимые, но присутствуют как минимум в двух наиболее популярных оболочках: *bash* и *zsh*.

Comment: Совершенно точный и весьма развернутый ответ.

Answer (score 1):

В скриптах нужно указывать, кто должен выполнять эту команду:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ./dir1/dir2/dir3
```

Comment: Точно, спасибо, забыл.