# Как выполнить команду в другом каталоге?

Tags: bash, macos

Создаю файл `test.command` с содержимым

```
mono /Users/wlad2/Desktop-1_1/AdvancetsParser2.exe
```

Файл находится по пути `/Users/wlad2/Desktop-1_1/AdvancetsParser2.exe`. При запуске программа начинает считывать файл `domen.txt` из текущей папки, однако при запуске файла он почему то начинает ссылаться в корень `/Users/wlad2/`и искать файл там.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если я правильно понимаю настройки вашего PS1 (`w2:~ wlad2`), текущим каталогом как раз и является ваш домашний каталог (`~`). соответственно, это [свойство](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/458278/178576) наследуется дочерним процессом `..2.exe` и он пытается работать с файлом `~/domen.txt`. а какого поведения вы ожидали?

Comment: А как его временно поменять (текущий каталог)? Или есть ли альтернативы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не совсем улавливаю, какой смысл вы вкладываете в слова «временно поменять», но если вам надо, чтобы команда `mono ...` выполнялась в другом текущем каталоге, добавьте перед ней в файле `test.command` команду смены текущего каталога, так, чтобы файл `test.command` выглядел примерно так:

```
cd /каталог.из.которого.надо.брать.файл.domen.txt/
mono /Users/wlad2/Desktop-1_1/AdvancetsParser2.exe
```