# cd не работает в скрипте

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, scripts

скрипт для деплоя джанго проекта на ubuntu nginx server
`import os  a = input("your directory path : ") os.system(' cd ' + a)`

я хочу чтоб про правильном введении адреса меня перекидовало в папку но почему то команда 'cd' не работает а 'ls' все ок показывает

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html используйте `os.chdir`. `cd` это внутренняя команда оболочки.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/458233/178576

Answer (score 4):

`cd` работает как и ожидается: он меняет текущий каталог для процесса который его вызывает (я тут всё немного упрощаю, но пока и так сойдёт). Ваша проблема что `os.system` создаёт новый процесс для которого `cd` и меняет каталог. Каталог в процессе Python, где живёт ваш скрипт, остаётся неизменным.

Используйте [os.chdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir). Он поменяет текущий каталог для процесса Python в котором исполнится.

Надеюсь я вам помог. А теперь важное: если возможно, никогда не меняйте каталог внутри процессов. Это очень, очень плохая идея. Текущий каталог придуман для удобства пользователя при вводе команд в консоли. Программы отлично обходятся без этого.

Answer (score 2):

Для указания директории в скрипте используйте `os.chdir(YOU_DIR)`